# ML. Correctly using "case of" inside functions

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, case, ml

So I've got this function:

```
fun propagate (Num a) = Num a
    | propagate (Var x) = Var x 
    | propagate (BinOp(f, Num a, Num b)) = 
            case f of PLUS => Num (a+b)
                | MINUS => Num (a-b)
                | MULT => Num (a*b)
                | DIV => if b<>0 then Num (a div b)
                    else raise CompileError
    | propagate (BinOp(_,x,y)) = (BinOp(_,propagate(x), propagate(y));
```

and I get these syntax errors:

```
stdIn:76.29-76.32 Error: syntax error: deleting  EQUALOP LPAREN
stdIn:76.67 Error: syntax error found at SEMICOLON
```

can anyone please help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Missing ) on the last line.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get: stdIn:76.27-76.32 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN EQUALOP LPAREN
stdIn:76.68 Error: syntax error found at SEMICOLON

Comment: It's been forever I wrote ML, and I don't have it installed but (1) I wouldn't put () around the last BinOp, (2) would put () around the case (I dont think ML has a layout rule) (3) I would not the match on the operator inside propagate but in a separate function. See if any of those helps.

Comment: On the last line replace the `_`s with some variable name.

Comment: Thank you both!! You really helped me! I love this community!